# Where to store api client key in grails

Tags: grails

I'd like to store api key in my grails application. Api key should be global and can be changed every several minutes or hours.

Where is the best place to store this key globally? 
I don't want to store it in database, guess that config is the best place.
But I suppose that config is a good place to store constants, not changeable data.

So, where to store api key globally?

**Update:** maybe class with static fields like `String apiKey` will be enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Api key should be global and can be changed every several minutes or hours.

Why would an API key change so frequently?

> guess that config is the best place. But I suppose that config is a good place to store constants, not changeable data.

Normally properties in `Config.groovy` are read-only, but there's nothing to prevent you modifying them, e.g.

```
class MyController {
  def grailsApplication

  def updateApiKey(String newKey) {
    grailsApplication.config.apiKey = newKey
  }
}
```

Comment: I was wrong, api key could be changed just when expired